# Issue with empty space value in countries list

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am currently working on a Spring project and I faced an issue with countries list.
The following list is a list of countries, I need to have a country with name emptySpace and id 0. the list is displaying countries successfully but this one country with empty space value is displayed by its id instead of its value, and if I full the empty space with any value, like "good job" it will show good job in the country list.

```
<c:forEach var="country" items="${country}">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${country.entityId == companyDetails.countryId}">
            <form:option value="${country.entityId}" selected="selected">${country.name}</form:option>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            <form:option value="${country.entityId}">${country.name}</form:option>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</c:forEach>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I don't do Spring, so I may be wrong, but try `&nbsp;` instead of "empty space" or try to just add a HTML `<option value="0"></option>` right below the `<select>` yourself instead of putting it in the list.

Comment: May there be any problem with the country.entityId or country.name values that have any "html character" which may be interferring the html syntax (and causing a problem)? I suggest using <c:out value="" /> tag to escape these characters and avoid any problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `label` attribute instead of tag body for passing label value:

```
<form:option value="${country.entityId}" label = "${country.name}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using any feature of the spring form:option tag, try using the html <option> tag instead.  I will not do any automatic substitutions.